# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array' with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I'm trying to use a List containing string arrays, but when I attempt to access the array elements using square brackets, I receive an error.

My List of arrays is declared like this:

```
public List<Array> alphabet = new List<Array>();
```

I also have a string array declared like this:

```
 string[] encrypted = new string[text.Length];
```

I am able to access one array, but not the other

```
string a = alphabet[1][2]; // this gives me an error

string b = encrypted[1]; // this works fine
```

Comment: If `alphabet` is a list of arrays containing strings, why are you applying `ToString()` to the array elements?

Comment: Im not really sure what you're asking. Please clarify

Comment: Have you tried using `.ElementAt(...`?

Comment: How is `alphabet` declared?

Comment: Of which declaration are you speaking? The first code line is a statement, not a declaration. Also, if a letter is not in `alphabetc`, you will get an index of -1 which will throw an exception when accessing `alphabet[-1]`.

Comment: Please show us the declarations of `encrypted`, `alphabet`, `text` and `alphabetc`. Since the indexing does not fit together with the declaration, we need to know the declarations.

Comment: I basically need to assign a string to encrypted, but the strings in which get assigned to it are in arrays that are stored in the List called alphabet. I have edited my post to include more information.

Comment: See my answer - if you bring in the `System.Linq` namespace you can use `yourArray.ElementAt(n)`.

Comment: @PeteGO if it's an `Array`, why not just use `array.GetValue(index)`?

Comment: Closed as "Off Topic"? This is a perfectly legitimate question and it absolutely is about programming.

Comment: Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Error is pretty straightforward; you can't use an indexer on an `Array`. `Array` class is a base class for all array types, and arrays are *implicitly* inherit from Array. But, `Array` itself doesn't have an indexer. Here is a demonstration of your error:

```
int[] numbers = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

numbers[2] = 11; // Okay

Array arr = numbers as Array;

arr[2] = 11; // ERROR!
```

So if you want to use the indexer, change your element type to an array of something for example:

```
public List<string[]> alphabet = new List<string[]>();
```

Comment: Well actually you can use indexer on Array, but by default it is hidden and you need casting to access it. System.Array implements interface System.Collections.IList, which have indexer. ((IList)arr)[0] will work

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward but is pretty counterintuitive. You'd expect to be able to index an array by definition. It even has an indexer, as @SARI stated. And in our case the "definition" is nothing else but the abstract class `Array`.  
Now there probably is a strong corner case reason for disallowing indexing but that's another story.

Answer (score 18):

Try using `.ElementAt`.  It works on anything that implements IEnumerable, including collections that aren't indexed.

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

I've split your statement up into multiple statements so it's easier to identify the offending line.

Please note - ElementAt is an extension method and you will need to be using the `System.Linq` namespace to use it.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Then in your method:

```
var n = getnumber(text.ElementAt(i));

var items = alphabet.ElementAt(n);

encrypted[i] = items.ElementAt(symnumb).ToString();
```

Comment: error on the last line. 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt' and no extension method 'ElementAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Edited this answer by accident (wanted to edit my own answer!). Have rolled back. Sorry.

Comment: user2517958 - you will need to be `using System.Linq`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596490/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-system-array-with-c-sha#comment56705505_23596490

Comment: Yay @PeteGO!  I'd never run into ElementAt before.  Thanks.

Comment: . 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'

Comment: @Jessedegans see my comment about `using System.Linq`

Comment: This is not true, System.Array implements only IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>, while ElementAt() is only available on IEnumerable<T>, what you can do it is either 1) use Cast<T>() on an IEnumerable to cast it to the type IEnumerable<T> you want, or in case you don't care on the type then do Cast<object>(), otherwise 2) use GetValue() as in the answeor of @JeppeStigNielsen

Answer (score 11):

You should not use the type `Array` in your code, so change your

```
public List<Array> alphabet = new List<Array>();
```

into e.g.

```
public List<string[]> alphabet = new List<string[]>();
```

or

```
public List<List<string>> alphabet = new List<List<string>>();
```

If you stick to `Array` for some reason, you cannot use `expr[i]` but will have to do `expr.GetValue(i)`, but I discourage it because the declared return type is `object`, and you will end up with a lot of casting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but the way you are referring to an element of array is wrong:

```
        int[] a4 = {1, 3, 2, 4, 5};
        string[] a5 = new string[5] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "z"};
       
        List<Array> alphabet = new List<Array>();

        alphabet.Add(a4);
        alphabet.Add(a5);

        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(alphabet[0].GetValue(2));
        string x2 = Convert.ToString(alphabet[1].GetValue(4));

        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < alphabet[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"element {i} of the alphabet list, element {j} of array =  {alphabet[i].GetValue(j)}");        
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SetValue(Object, Int32)
Sets a value to the element at the specified position in the one-dimensional Array. The index is specified as a 32-bit integer.

arr.SetValue(2, 11)