# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type array - VB.NET to C# Conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm quite new to C# and have been running some conversion from VB.NET to C#.

I understand indexing doesn't work with `Array`s in C#, which is causing me a bit of trouble.

For example, the line:

`myUserName = Conversions.ToString(myUserNameFields[0]);`

Gives an error that one `cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type array`

I was hoping this would be a quick fix but I've been struggling to fix it. I've found similar problems from Googling:

[Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Array' with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596490/cannot-apply-indexing-with-to-an-expression-of-type-system-array-with-c-sha)

...but struggling to directly apply this to my code without completely overhauling it.

Is there a quick fix to something like this?

```
    internal static string getCurrentUserName()
    {
        string myUserName;
        myUserName = MyProject.User.Name;
        Array myUserNameFields = myUserName.Split('\\');
        if (myUserNameFields.Length == 1)
        {
            myUserName = Conversions.ToString(myUserNameFields[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            myUserName = Conversions.ToString(myUserNameFields[1]);
        }

        return myUserName;
    }
```

Comment: Don't declare it as `Array`, declare it as `string[]` or just use `var`.

Comment: Ah thanks! That was simpler than I thought it would be

Comment: `String.Split` returns a `string[]` array in VB.NET and C#. Don't cast it to an `Array`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected C#:

```
internal static string GetCurrentUserName() //methods, even non public ones, use PascalCase
{
    var myUserName = MyProject.User.Name;          //do not declare then assign on the next line. Use var where the type on the right is obvious
    var myUserNameFields = myUserName.Split('\\'); //use var
    if (myUserNameFields.Length == 1)
    {
        myUserName = myUserNameFields[0];          //do not use Conversions.ToString to convert a string to a string. myUserNameFields is already a string; it needs no conversion
    }
    else
    {
        myUserName = myUserNameFields[1];          
    }

    return myUserName;
}
```

Consider also:

```
internal static string GetCurrentUserName() 
{
    var ns = MyProject.User.Name.Split('\\'); 
    return ns.Length == 1 ? ns[0] : ns[1];
}
```

Or even this, if you're after the `joe` in usernames that are like `joe` or `domain\joe`:

```
internal static string GetCurrentUserName() 
{
    return MyProject.User.Name.Split('\\').Last();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this! This helps a lot.